# Can I backup Ironman saves in XCOM 2?

Tags: xcom-2

I'm playing ironman mode. Unfortunately, XCOM 2 is currently full of LOS and interface bugs and it's really easy to lose multiple operatives and/or a mission to them.

Is there a way to backup and load ironman saves, ideally without closing the game?

Comment: Something that worked in XCOM 2012 was the fact that, barring manual save + exits, the only time the game saved was at the end of the turn. If you killed the process mid-turn, you could get a do-over. I'd try that for XCOM 2 as well.

Comment: You probably can, but you will forever know in your heart of hearts, you are a [save scummer](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=savescumming) - i.e. Someone who subverts a permadeath save mechanic to get props for completing "hardcore mode", without in fact being hardcore.

Comment: :O ...Heresy!!!

Comment: The obvious choice is to simply not play on iron man mode?  But I digress.

Comment: Anybody else get here after watching https://youtu.be/lUvd4B58-q0?t=1858 ? (Last part of a 25-part series...)

Comment: To my surprise, ironman mode is more entertaining... who knew..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, if you go into your `My Documents/my games/XCOM2/XComGame/SaveData` folder, you can see your save files. Identify the save you want by the timestamp, then copy it somewhere else. You can do this while the game is running without issue. If you want to roll back an Ironman save, you need to exit to the main menu before you copy the old save over, or it will automatically overwrite it when you try to load (it saves the ironman campaign, then tries to load the save, which it just overwrote) - but you don't have to quit the game entirely. Quit to menu, copy, then load. It works both in the Geoscape and in the Tactical game mode.

Comment: It works in tactical mode.

Answer (score 2):

For Linux gamers, According to [PC Gaming Wiki](https://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/XCOM_2#Save_game_data_location) the file is in:

`~/.local/share/feral-interactive/XCOM2/VFS/Local/my games/XCOM2/XComGame/SaveData/`