# Penalty of removing facility

Tags: xcom-2

I'm currently out of room to build another **Resistance Comms**. I'm thinking of removing one of:

1. **Guerilla Tactics Schoo**l (got all the features it offers)
2. **Psi Lab** (got 2 magi)
3. **Defense Matrix** (got one base defense mission but UFO is
   still hunting me)

Will I lost my Guerilla Tactics bonuses and magi if I remove the corresponding facilities? What would you choose in this situation?

Comment: I doubt you'd lose your Magi, since the Psi Lab is only there to train them. As for the GTS: if it's like *XCOM: EU*, you'll only lose your perks as long as the school isn't built. As soon as it's built again, the perks will come back.

Comment: Damn it! I can't even try it as I'm playing in Ironman mode.

Comment: You *can* try it. See [Can I backup Ironman saves in XCOM 2?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/255553/108003).

Comment: Additionally I'd say consider workshop and laboratory for demolition. Workshop doesn't do anything, if you have 8+ engineers and all facilities excavated. Laboratory is very weak, especially on difficulties below legend.

Comment: I don't get it... 2 resistance comms are all you need... you don't have slots for those?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just tried it out on one of my own saves. Deleting the Psi Labs does not get rid of any psionic soldiers, but removing the Guerrilla Tactics School will prevent you from taking advantage of any bonuses you may have purchased through it. Rebuilding the facility restores those bonuses.

If it were my game, I would remove either the Psi Labs  or Defense Matrix -- Squad Size upgrades on Ironman are crucial.